# Newline in textarea on some clients not working

Tags: html, forms

I,ve a problem with a textarea in html that contains a newline character \n. On some Clients it showns the newline without problems and other clients ignores the newline. I tested it with simple adding test\ntest in the textarea.

How can it be? Its a Problem with html encoding?

Tranks for helping

Comment: if there are possible windows clients you should use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: We are yousing different clients Linux/Windows/Mac